# Trying to make the inputs into a row, but have the labels above the inputs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, label

I know the answer's probably incredibly obvious, but after even researching I still have no idea what I should do. I want to have the inputs in a row, but have the labels be above the inputs.
I've tried making the input and label display flex and flex-direction column, however that just turns everything into a column.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[An example of the problem I'm working on. The number inputs are below the labels. The labels say "DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxnwm.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
  <main>
    <section class="wrap">
      <section class="inputs">

      <label for="day">DAY</label>
      <input type="number" name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD">

      <label for="month">MONTH</label>
      <input type="number" name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM">

      <label for="year">YEAR</label>
      <input type="number" name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY">
    </section>

    <div id="line"></div>

      <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>years</p>
      <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>months</p>
      <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>days</p>
    </section>

  </main>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
label {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

input {
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: var(--Smokey-grey) solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I had something for the class .inputs, however I commented it out as it was causing issues in my markup. Here is what I had, in case it's helpful:

```
/* .inputs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 10px;
} */
```

However, I removed this because since the .inputs include the labels, it caused the labels to be on the same line as the inputs.

This is my first time reaching out on this site, so please let me know if I should add anymore snippets!
If it helps any, I'm currently using the Bootstrap framework.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes I am! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each label and input pair is wrapped in an additional  element with the class input-container. The .inputs section has display: flex, flex-wrap: wrap, and justify-content: center properties to make the input containers wrap to the next line if the width is not sufficient. The margin: 0 10px on the .input-container class creates spacing between the input containers. The labels will appear directly above each input, and all the inputs will be positioned on the same line.

CSS:

```
label {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .inputs {
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .input-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  input {
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: var(--Smokey-grey) solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<main>
    <section class="wrap">
    <section class="inputs">
        <div class="input-container">
        <label for="day">DAY</label>
        <input type="number" name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD">
        </div>

        <div class="input-container">
        <label for="month">MONTH</label>
        <input type="number" name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM">
        </div>

        <div class="input-container">
        <label for="year">YEAR</label>
        <input type="number" name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY">
        </div>
    </section>

    <div id="line"></div>

    <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>years</p>
    <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>months</p>
    <p><span class="purple"> -- </span>days</p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please __edit__ your answer to make it more clear and formatted for future viewers.

Comment: Thank you so much! It didn't instantly do the trick, but it got me on the right track to figuring it out! :) Thank you. I found that adding "style="display:inline-block;margin-right:20px;" to the input-container divs (inline) helped.